# How can I get rid off a character to get the desired output

Tags: c, output

There are many questions about printing triangles here but this one is a little bit different so I hope you don't mind seeing another one.

I am trying to generate the following output:

```
+
|\
| \
|  \
+---+
```

I wrote the following code but the output I am getting is:

```
+
|
|\
| \
|  \
+---+
```

How can I get rid of the `|` character on the second line to get the desired output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k, r;
    printf("Enter number of rows: \n");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    printf("+\n");
    for (i = 1; i < r - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                printf("|");
            } else if (j > 0 && j < i - 1) {
                printf(" ");
            } else if (j == i - 1) {
                printf("\\");
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("+");
    for (k = 0; k < r - 3; k++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("+\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start the loop from 2, which means 2 characters will be printed in that line.

Change

```
for (i=1;i<r-1;i++) {
```

to

```
for (i=2;i<r-1;i++) {
```

This will produce the desired output for `r=6`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much, much cleaner way to print this whole triangle.  I'll break it down into smaller functions to make it much more clear what is going on.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printTriangleRow(int rowNumber) {
    printf("|");
    for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; ++i) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\\\n");
}

void printTriangleBottom(int sideLength) {
    printf("+");
    for(int i = 0; i < sideLength; ++i) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("+\n");
}

void printTriangleWithSideLength(int sideLength) {
    printf("+\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < sideLength; ++i) {
        printTriangleRow(i);
    }
    printTriangleBottom(sideLength);
}

int main() {
    int rowCount;
    printf("Enter number of rows: \n");
    scanf("%d", &rowCount);
    printTriangleWithSideLength(rowCount);
}
```

Now, if there's a bug in here, it's WAY easier to understand what's going on with each part, identify the bug, and fix it.